# Create SQLite Database Import FMDatabse.h File

Tags: sqlite

I am adding the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) files in my swift project...

 as per [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345902/importing-and-quering-through-an-sqlite-database-in-swift-ios) I have to `#import "FMDB.h"` to my bridging header

 I have bridging header FileName : FMDB.h

 Then have I create the new  bridging header with other name and add it my fmdb folder?

I have also Implement the code

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType:"sqlite")

let database = FMDatabase(path: path)

if !database.open() {
    println("Unable to open database")
    return
}
```

but it's not working.

Please help me out

Comment: Palak have also same type of Problem

Answer (score 2):

You can add code like this

```
let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let docsDir : String = dirPaths[0] as! String
databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("db.sqlite")
if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {
   let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
   if contactDB.open() {
   //write your code
   }
}
```

Its work for me!!!